# How to call html from jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a website with data display, user can edit this data. After a user doing so, I want a modal to confirm the change.

I currently doing it with alert function.
But I read somewhere in this forum that we shoud avoid using alert() outside of debuging.
So I looked for a modal exemple in html on the web.
Now I'm wondering how to call this html from jquery. I tried .html() in vain.
Here is my current code, the alert is still work.

```
function updatedata(id, nom, ) {  
        $.ajax({
            // Action
            url: 'admin',
            // Method
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                // Get value
                id: id,
                nom: nom
            },
            success:function(response){
                console.log("success");
                $("div#myModalEdit").html();
                alert(nom + " à été modifier bdd");
            }
        });
    };
```

**EDIT:** Thank you for your answers, I finally followed the suggestion of using toastr

Comment: html will give you the content, it will not display a popup. there are several nice libraries, try something like , https://sweetalert2.github.io/  it has tutorials on how to get started

Comment: *avoid using alert() outside of debuging* - mostly, it's ugly and blocks the browser.   However, don't use it for debugging either as it can mess with events such as focus/blur - use `console.log` for debugging - it's also much less intrusive when you happen to forget to remove it and release.

Comment: I wanted to avoid installing a library if possible, but thank you I will try sweetAlert2

Comment: *modal to confirm the change* - can I suggest instead a *toaster* or "popup" rather than a "modal"/"dialog" - eg [toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) as these are much less intrusive to the user:   "fill in form" "click save" "your data has been saved" - user then has to click "OK" or similar to close the dialog - so having to click twice to save and continue.  It's not good UX.

Comment: `$("div#myModalEdit").html();` may need to have been `$("div#myModalEdit").show();`

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your question is too broad. The internet is chock full of tutorials on creating modal dialogs. That's not a new technique and you shouldn't expect us to write you yet another how-to. If you have a more specific question, please revise to ask it.

Comment: As I say in my question, I already found code for html modal on internet. I NEVER asked anyone to write me code neither expected it.  Since I'm new on web developpement, futhermore in dynamic one, I wanted to know how to show a modal after a dynamic event, not how to write a modal.